# ¿Cómo reproducir un vídeo almacenado en una base de datos utilizando php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

he almacenado un video en formato .mp4 en un campo longblob y quiero consultarlo y poder reproducirlo en la pagina.
Aquí debajo coloco el código de lo que tengo hecho.

```
     <?php
     $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM autos ");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)){
       $location = $row['foto'];

       echo "<video width='400' controls >";
       echo "<source src='$location' type='video/mp4' >";

       echo "</video>";
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Hola @Leonardo, no es recomendable guardar videos y imágenes en base de datos sino subir el fichero a un directorio en el servidor y y guardar la referencia en base de datos. Te estas enviando algún error en pantalla por favor colocalo. Gracias

Comment: Hola @YoelRodriguez no, no me envía ningún error

Comment: @YoelRodriguez simplemente sale un cuadro  del tag video pero no reproduce

Comment: Porque en lugar el video en la base de datos no guardas solo la referencia de la ruta y el video lo colocas en un directorio en el servidor y en tu **src* colas la ruta de de donde esta el video

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma, pero me gustaría saber el código para poder ver el vídeo de esta forma